# What are the effect of setting yb_enable_read_committed_isolation = true in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

The flag `--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation` is set to false by default when starting a yb-tserver. What are the side effects of setting it to true?

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of Yugabyte database the Read Committed isolation level, set with PostgreSQL syntax, was actually using the higher level Repeatable Read. With the introduction of Read Committed semantic, the Read Committed set at PostgreSQL level (YSQL) can now use the true Read Committed semantic.

It is not set by default for backward compatibility of Read Committed isolation level transactions. Setting it to true has no impact on other isolation levels.

In summary, `--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=false` is good to be compatible for applications build for previous versions of YugabyteDB. `--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=true` is good for applications build for PostgreSQL migrated to YugabyteDB